# why mock.patch doesn't work while trying to mock a function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

The structure of the project is

[image]

main.py

```
from src.tools.tool_a import fun


def main_fun():
    fun()
```

tools_a.py

```
def fun():
    raise Exception('')
```

test_fun.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.main import main_fun


@patch('src.tools.tool_a.fun')
def test_main_fun(fun):
    main_fun()
```

If I run pytest `tests/test_fun.py` I get an exception from method `fun()`. I already mocked it so do not understand what is the correct way of mocking it.

Comment: You patch where things are _used_, not where they're _defined_: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch.

Comment: ah! you mean @patch('src.main.fun')